# Unexpected "No matches" error for selected table node

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to obtain the table on this website:
https://ultrasignup.com/results_event.aspx?did=31930

I want all attributes (all columns and rows) of the table.

I used chrome developer to look at the css attributes of the table and determined that the ID was `list_results`. Therefore I used `list_results` in my code.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

data <- html_session("https://ultrasignup.com/results_event.aspx?did=31930")

data %>% 
html_node("#jqgh_list_formattime , #jqgh_list_gender , #jqgh_list_age , #jqgh_list_state , #jqgh_list_city , #jqgh_list_firstname , #jqgh_list_place") %>%
html_text()
```

This produces the following error:

`Error: No matches`

I am new to using rvest and scraping webpages. Any advice/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: What is `%>%` doing in this case?

Comment: @giraffehere: the last three lines of code are all one chunk, it just didn't come out in the post.

Comment: It might help to look into the documentation of `html_node` and `html_text`.